# Fixing "Configuration cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, hbase

All,

I am trying out an [HBase tutorial](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/package-summary.html) and using Eclipse as my IDE.
The following 1 line of code is the problem but I don't know why.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
```

**Error in Eclipse**

```
Configuration cannot be resolved to a type
```

1. I imported all jars from my $HBASE_HOME/lib
2. I am using HBase 1.2.5

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Import the class

Comment: If you look at the screenshot it shows that it is imported

Comment: No! There is an Import `HBaseConfiguration` and `Connection` but not `Configuration`

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying but no need to downvote (if it was you) a well-documented question. The Apache tutorial mentioned above, which I followed does not include import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

Comment: @Slinky look at my answer.

Comment: @slinky thanks, and good luck!

Comment: BTW: In eclipse you can press shift+ctrl+O. That helps you importing referenced classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Configuration` class part of **HBase 1.2.5**,  you can look through its [JavaDoc](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html) and you will see it's not there. What is being returned from the method [HBaseConfiguration.create()](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html); is actually of type `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` which is part of [Apache Hadoop Main](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/package-summary.html). you need to import that package to your project as well.

### Note

In Eclipse if you hover your mouse over the class it cannot resolve it will provide suggestions for what classes you can import. If you are not seeing it there it is because the class doesn't exist in your classpath.

[image]